# SwiftUI cant get Firebase Firestore instance

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I can't seem to connect to my Firestore database. The specific error I am getting is "Failed to get FirebaseApp instance. Please call FirebaseApp.configure() before using Firestore". However, I've already called the configure function. Here is my code for the section I am writing:

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
```

I have also properly configured Firebase in AppDelegate like so

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
```

Any help on this at all would be really appreciated, I cant seem to figure out what's going on.

This is the section in reference for context:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import Foundation

    struct Practioner: Identifiable {
        var id: ObjectIdentifier

        var name: String
        var email: String
        var gender: String
        var provider: String
        var education: String
        var subspeciality: String
        var languages: String //fix this to array
        var indigenous: Bool
        var lgbtq: Bool
        var rural: Bool
    }

    public struct DemographicsView: View {
        @State var genderSel = ""
        @State var providerSel = ""
        @State var educationSel = ""
        @State var subspecialtySel = ""
        @State var languageSel = ""
        @State var indigenousSel = false
        @State var lgbtqSel = false
        @State var ruralSel = false

        @EnvironmentObject var settings: UserSettings
        @EnvironmentObject var session: sessionStore

        var genders = ["Male", "Female", "Other"]

        init(){
            UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear


         }

    public var body: some View {
        VStack {

            NavigationView {

                Form {

                    Text("Demographics")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .padding(.bottom, 20)

                    Text("Please specify the following details about 
     yourself")
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .padding(.bottom, 20)

                    Section(){

                        Picker(selection: $genderSel, label: 
    Text("Gender")) {

                            ForEach(0 ..< genders.count){
                                Text(self.genders[$0]).tag($0)
                            }
                        }


                        Picker(selection: $providerSel, label: 
    Text("Provider Type")) {

                            Text("Doctor").tag(1)
                            Text("Nurse").tag(2)
                            Text("Other").tag(3)
                        }

                        Picker(selection: $educationSel, label: 
    Text("Country of education")) {

                            Text("Canada").tag(1)
                            Text("USA").tag(2)
                            Text("Other").tag(3)
                        }

                        Picker(selection: $subspecialtySel, label: 
    Text("Subspecialty")) {

                            Text("OGBYN").tag(1)
                            Text("Family doctor").tag(2)
                            Text("Other").tag(3)
                        }

                        Picker(selection: $languageSel, label: 
    Text("Language(s)")) {

                            Text("English").tag(1)
                            Text("French").tag(2)
                            Text("Malayalam").tag(3)
                        }



                    }

                    Toggle(isOn: $indigenousSel) {
                        Text("Indigenous")
                    }

                    Toggle(isOn: $lgbtqSel) {
                        Text("LGBTQ+ (optional)")
                    }

                    Toggle(isOn: $ruralSel) {
                        Text("Rural")
                    }

                    Section(){

                        Button(action: {

                            let db = Firestore.firestore()



                        }) {
                            LoginButtonView(textField: "Sign up")
                        }.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, 
    minHeight: 0,maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)

                    }

                }

            }.navigationBarHidden(true)
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Home"))
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.top, .bottom])

        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello Abhi Santhosh. Thank you for asking the question. [Please don't post screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1040347) of text. They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question.

Comment: Sorry about that, I can do that right now

Comment: The code is the question starting at import SwiftUI is pretty much unrelated to Firebase so it can be removed. In general, it helps us to help you when relevant code and initialization steps are included and also a description of what troubleshooting you've done and an indication of what line of code is not working correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
import FirebaseFirestore
```

at the top and try building the app again. Worked for me!

**Example :**

```
import FirebaseFirestore
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import Foundation
```

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration *let db = Firestore.firestore()* should be declared at the top of your Class (ViewModel) and not in a Button. There might be other mistakes, which can't be elaborated with just such little code provided.

Comment: Where is your ContentView or did you change your rootView to DemographicsView? I see different kind of problems in your code and would suggest to start over again for the moment with an Empty View to narrow down the problem.

Comment: My content view is another view that is still my root view, I'm using demographicsview as a different page on my app

Comment: Test what I told you in my answer and my comment. You seem to use Firestore somewhere in your App and I don't see it in what you have posted (except the Button, but as I understand you the error occurs without pressing the Button).

Comment: Agree with @Kuhlemann - you should extract data access into a view model (or a store), and instantiate the `db` instance there. However, the error message indicates your configuration file might not be included in your project. Make sure to download your project's `GoogleService-Info.plist` file and drag it into your project. Then, make sure it is a member of your compile target.

Answer (score 0):

There are three steps to initializing and working with Firestore. It's possible one is missing (this shows the steps for Swift, SwiftUI is similar)

1) .configure in AppDelegate

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions... {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }
```

2) Set up a class var within a ViewController (for example)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var db: Firestore!
```

3) Initialize the class var in the ViewController (for example)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.db = Firestore.firestore()
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone comes across this while trying to run SwiftUI like previews for UIKit code. Or more specifically doing a SwiftUI UIKit integration with UIViewControllerRepresentable...

Call FirebaseApp.configure() again when overriding viewDidLoad in the view controller worked for me (even if its already in your AppDelegate). For example...

```
class MyController: UIViewController {    
     override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           FirebaseApp.configure()
           self.db = Firestore.firestore()
        }
}
```